# Ajax call PHP Mysql public static function

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Im getting a hard time with this guys,
How can i call this kind of php class?
Here rest my problem *remote: 'myData.php?jquery=%jquery'*
What's the correct call format?

myData.php

```
public static function getproduct($p){
        $sql = "select * from products where code like '%$p%' or name like '%$p%' or id like '%$p%'";
        $query = Executor::doit($sql);
        return Model::many($query[0],new ProductData());
    }
```

From Js/Ajax like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $('input.city').typeahead({
                name: 'city',
                remote: 'myData.php?jquery=%jquery'

            });

        })
```

Thanks!

Comment: inside myData.php, include/use the file where your class is defined and call  ClassName::getproduct($p)

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489109/ajax-request-and-php-class-functions

Comment: @user3099298 Im really stupid i didnt get it. Could you give me an more simple example?. Cheers.

Comment: @Ima The posted PHP/Mysql function is already inside myData.php (Who has 2 more functions), so, is like i'm calling it directly, is this wrong?

Comment: Ypu cannot call directly from javascript, you have to call a url with javascript (via Ajax) and that url should be handled in a php file. That php file can invoke any php function you want.  Read for more info on ajax: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Product.php file represents your class file. viewProduct.php is your view file. When you enter text on city input field, jQuery will pass that value to class file using GET method. If class file get a value from `myRequest`, then it will call static function and send output to the view file.

Product.php

```
class Product{
    public static function getproduct($p){
        // add your SQL queries
        return "This is return value ".$p;
    }
}

// call static function 
if(isset($_GET['myRequest'])) {
     echo Product::getproduct($_GET['myRequest']);
}
```

viewProduct.php

```
<input type="text" name="city" id="city"/>

<span id="result"></span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#city").keyup(function(){
        var txt = $(this).val();
        $.get("product.php", {myRequest: txt}, function(result){
            $("#result").html(result);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Now I'm Getting an Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) . I leave you a pastebin to see how my myData.php looks http://pastebin.com/CExBQdsd

Comment: @fecapeluda  Create two files in separate directory(not your actual project folder) and run above code, then you can understand how it is working. Then apply the concept to your actual project.